# dbus screensaver "ActiveChanged" signals not emitted from Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, dbus, screensaver, qdbus

I am unable to connect qdbus screensaver ActiveChanged() signal for Ubuntu,but following code works well in Fedora.

```
 QDBusConnection sessionConnection=QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
 sessionConnection.connect("org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver","/org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver","org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver","ActiveChanged",this,SLOT(handleScreenSaverActiveChanged(bool)));
```

but gnome's Screensaver is connected and work in ubuntu as i want.

```
 sessionConnection.connect("org.gnome.ScreenSaver","/org/gnome/ScreenSaver","org.gnome.ScreenSaver","ActiveChanged",this,SLOT(handleScreenSaverActive(bool)));
```

Is there any other generic signals which works in all desktop Environment.
Thanks